Continuity and lebesgue integrability of integral function, proof verification
Suppose that $f\in L^1(\mathbb R, \mathcal B_{\mathbb R} ,m)$ where $m$ is the standard lebesgue measure. For fixed $h$, let us define:
$$\phi(x)= \frac{1}{2h} \int_{x-h}^{x+h} f(t) dt $$
Show that $\phi$ is measureable and that $\|\phi \|_1 \leq \|f\|_1$.
For the first part, I have tried the following:
We will show that $\phi $ is continuous on $\mathbb R$. For this, let $x_n \to x$ be an arbitrary sequence in $\mathbb R$. We define, $E_n = [x_n -h , x_n +h]$ and $E= [x-h,x+h]$. Note that
$$f\chi_{E_n} \to f\chi_{E}$$
pointwise almost since for any $y \in \mathbb R$ (I feel like this is intuitively obvious, but I'm having a little trouble formulating the details). Next, $|f \chi_{E_n}| \leq |f|$, and since $f\chi_{E_n}, f\chi_E \in L^1$, we have by the DCT that
$$\int f\chi_{E_n} \to \int f\chi_E \text{ as } n\to \infty$$
which implies that for $n$ sufficiently large,
$$\frac{1}{2|h|} \left| \int_{E_n} f - \int_E f \right| \leq \epsilon$$
i.e. $\phi(x_n) \to \phi(x)$.
I am having trouble with the second part. Any suggestions?

This seems to be a correct proof.
For the convergence $\chi_{E_n}\rightarrow\chi_E$, consider points $t$ in $\mathbb{R}$ different from from $x+h$ and $x-h$; then there is a positive $\delta$ for which $(t-\delta,t+\delta)$ is either contained in it $(x-h,x+h)$ or its compliment. So, for sufficiently large $n$, we have that $\vert x_n-x\vert<\delta$ and then it should hold that $\chi_{E_n}(t)=\chi_E(t)$.
For the second part, $$\Vert\phi\Vert_1=\int_\mathbb{R}\vert\phi(t)\vert\ dt=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left\vert\frac{1}{2h}\int_{t-h}^{t+h}f(x)\ dx\right\vert dt\le\frac{1}{2\vert h\vert}\int_\mathbb{R}\int_{t-h}^{t+h}\vert f(x)\vert\ dxdt$$ and by Fubini's theorem, that equals $$\frac{1}{2\vert h\vert}\int_\mathbb{R}\int_{x-h}^{x+h}\vert f(x)\vert\ dtdx=\frac{1}{2\vert h\vert}\int_\mathbb{R}2\vert h\vert\vert f(x)\vert\ dx=\int_\mathbb{R}\vert f\vert\ dx=\Vert f\Vert_1.$$ Notice that the region of integration is $\{(x,t)\ \vert\ t-h\le x\le t+h\}$ which is equal to $\{(x,t)\ \vert\ x-h\le t\le x+h\}$, so that is why Fubini works like that (plus details of convergence, but those are standard).For every real $x$, we have that $\int_{x-h}^{x+h}\vert f(x)\vert\ dt=2\vert h\vert\vert f(x)\vert$ simply becuase $f(x)$ is constant with respect to $t$.

I will asume that $h>0$. The case $h<0$ is left to you.
$$2h\|\phi_1\|=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |\int_{x-h}^{x+h} f(t) dt| dx$$ $$ \le \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{t-h}^{t+h} |f(t)|  dx dt$$ $$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}2h |f(t)| dt$$ $$=2h||f\|_1 .$$
I have used the fact that $x-h<t<x+h$ is equivalent to $t-h<x<t+h$.
Interchange of integrals is justified by Tonelli's Theorem.
